# How to connect remote EJB module from application client

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I have a EJB module in remote Glassfish server and application client in my computer. I want to connect from the application client to the remote EJB.

Here is the my EJB interface:

```
@Remote
public interface BookEJBRemote
{
    public String getTitle();
}
```

Here is the my ejb:

```
@Stateless
public class BookEJB implements BookEJBRemote
{

    @Override
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea";
    }
}
```

I have several questions :

1. Can I use Dependency Injection in the remote application client to connect to the ejb? If so what can i do to achieve this. Do i need to configure in the sun-ejb-jar.xml and sun-application-client.xml? In other words, if i use Dependency Injection like @EJB BookEJBRemote book; How application client container know what ejb to be injected? Where should i specify the information?
2. How can i run the application client? I tried to run package-appclient in the glassfish server to get appclient.jar and copy it to my computer. Then i type appclient.jar -client myAppClient.jar . It didn't work. How do i point the target server?
3. if i cannot use Dependency Injection in the client then i guess i have to use JNDI lookup. Do i need to configure jndi name in sun-ejb-jar.xml or in the sun-application-client.xml?

No matter how i try i never manage to run application client ? Can you guys put some working example? And thank you for every advises and examples?

Comment: You question is partially answered in [@EJB annotation in clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848675): Glassfish supports managing of standalone client applications if you run them via [`bin/appclient -client myprogram.jar`](http://www.ensode.net/glassfish_rich_ejb_clients.html). The client has to specify JNDI settings in [`jndi.properties`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42394/How-to-create-JBoss-ejb3-session-bean-standalone-c) and description of the service in [`application-client.xml`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B15897_01/web.1012/b15505/access.htm#sthref238).

Comment: I agree with this question.  Every single post I have read online just shows how to run an app client in netbeans.  There seems to be absolutely nothing whatsoever that explains how to run app clients outside of netbeans.  +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [tutorial Creating a Java Stand-Alone Client](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish).
Basically you need to

- setup JNDI by yourself since your client can't use the containers environment.
- Lookup the remote interface.
- And of course include the required jar files in your classpath

Comment: The tutorial that you have cited is quite old.  It is targeted to folks using NetBeans 6.1.  That was released a couple years ago.

Comment: @vkraemer The article says it has also been tested with 6.7.1

Comment: The link is now broken.