# What is Remote EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I want to know what is really local and remote EJB. Is remote an EJB which is the same jar file ? Is remote an EJB which is in another JVM ? What is it anyway? 
If I have deployed two different EAR files in the same server domain do I need to lookup for EJBs in each other? Lookup is achieved through annotations ? I mean EJB 3.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986993/how-to-connect-remote-ejb-module-from-application-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote EJBs are used in a distributed environment. The EJBs may run in one JVM, while their consumers run in another.

Local EJBs are used when you can guarantee that all consumers of the EJB are operating within the same JVM.

Comment: Technically correct although the terminology is a bit off - remote/local EJB INTERFACES, the exact same EJB may have both ;)

Comment: I wouldn't agree with anyone of you. A remote EJB is one that is accessed through his remote interface. All his parameters is transmitted by value and not by reference even if caller and EJB reside both in the same JVM.

Comment: Two EJB deployed in different jar files in the same container are in the same JVM ?