# EJB on a remote client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I have successfully compiled, deployed, and tested a simple, Remote, Stateless Session Beans on my local machine using this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html).

The program just prints out "Hello World" in NetBeans output window when run.

**However I wish to run the client application on another home machine which doesn't has GlassFish or JavaEE installed.** 
I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986993/how-to-connect-remote-ejb-module-from-application-client) here that, to do this I need to create a stand alone Java Application; however I am unsure about the steps to take to obtain the same result.

**I am new to EJB architecture.** Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. On the first step create standalone application. For example in main method get remote instance of the bean through InitialContext (I suppose, that you define Stateless bean through Remote Interface). Then you can work with bean. Please, remember remote access through InitialContext is different  on the different servers type (jboss,weblogic,glassfish). In final look at link: [InitialContext on jboss](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)